# $f(x)=x+\frac{1}{x}$ is distance decreasing

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus

Let $f:[1,\infty]\rightarrow [1,\infty]$ be defined by

$x\in [1,\infty]\mapsto:=f(x)=x+\frac{1}{x}$

$a)$ show that $f$ is distance decreasing by showing that $|f(x)-f(y)|<|x-y| ,\forall x\neq y$

$b)$ show that $f$ does not have a fixed point

### My attempt

$a)$ $$f(x)=x+1/x$$ $$f(y)=y+1/y$$ $$|f(x)-f(y)|=|x+\frac{1}{x}-y-\frac{1}{y}|$$

Not sure where to go from here...

$b)$ By definition of fixed point. If $f$ has a fixed point that we can solve $f(x)=x$.

$$x+\frac{1}{x}=x$$
$$\frac{1}{x}=0$$

Impossible.

Comment: "Not sure where to go from here..." Assume $x>y$ in order to get rid of the absolute value signs. Then compare to $x-y$, see which is bigger.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a), notice that
$$ \left| x+\frac{1}{x}-y-\frac{1}{y} \right| = \left| x-y + \frac{y-x}{xy} \right| = \lvert x-y \rvert \left| 1-\frac{1}{xy} \right|, $$
and of course the second factor is strictly between $0$ and $1$ since at least one of $x$ and $y$ is strictly larger than $1$.

---

b) looks fine.

Comment: I completely understand this answer, thanks! Out of curiosity, is there a way to somehow use the triangle inequality here too?

Comment: also how do we know at least one of $x$ and $y$ is larger than $1$?

Comment: It's stated in the question that $x \neq y$, so we can't have both of them being $1$.

Comment: Re: the triangle inequality, I don't think so: the signs of the terms are important here, and I can't see a way to get it to go the right way round.

Answer (score 5):

An alternative method is to use MVT. We know that $\exists c \in (x,y)$ such that
$$ \bigg |\frac{f(x) - f(y)}{x-y} \bigg | = |f'(c)| = 1 - \frac{1}{c^2}  < 1, $$
since $c > 1$, proves the claim.